# AWS/Ruby On Rails/Puma/Nginx Maximum number of requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, puma

I recently changed from passenger to puma because it was constantly giving me "request limit exceeded error" and I read online that passenger free version doesn't support multithreading. My backend application is hosted on two AWS c5xlarge instances and has and elastic load balancer on top. Can someone help me with the number of workers and threads I should set in puma config and a maximum number of concurrent requests I can serve with these settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer to your question. It depends on a lot of parameters.

You should create a benchmark script which sends a lot of requests from multiple process and/or threads, and if your server can handle a heavy load even from multiple instances, and see how many requests are served in a second.

After you have this benchmark test try to change the number of threads and workers, in order to increase the number of requests served using this benchmark.

I would start with one nginx worker and the number of threads as the number of cpu cores and increase or decrease according to the benchmark.